# Creating multiple layout overrides for category blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override, layout, category

I have looked at other questions on this matter, but would like to be clear on what is the 'correct' approach to this.
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715665/joomla-override-category-blog-output-multiple-times

I have already created an override for the category blog layout, this effects any menu items etc that point towards the Category Blog layout in my template.
//templates/template_name/html/com_content/category/blog.php / blog_children.php etc etc.

What I would now like to do is create a completely separate blog layout. Specifically this is for a Shop category in the main menu. I would like to style this completely differently to how my main category blog override is already created. What is the 'correct' method to complete this? Are there any walkthroughs/explanations on what needs to be created where to get me started.

Comment: This tut will set you on the right track, I guess : How to a Have a Different Category Blog Layout for a Specific Category in Joomla http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-a-have-a-different-category-blog-layout-for-a-specific-category-in-joomla

Comment: > did you also duplicate the .xml file? – wouho Mar 10 '15 at 14:48 Where do you find this xml file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just duplicate your blog.php override and rename it (e.g. shop.php). At that point it will be available as an alternative layout for Category Blog. You can also add child layouts, like shop_item.php and then reference these from shop.php so you can style each item rendered in the category view.

Comment: I tried that but the alternate layout in the menu item was not available. I also tried changing the layout on the category to the override but again that didn't actually use the override file. Is there any other step?

Comment: did you also duplicate the .xml file?

Comment: That is what I was missing, without the xml file it doesn't work. Thanks